# Discrepancy in translated model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I translated a solidworks 2014 model twice and found that there are some differences in the translation when we look at it in the viewer (same viewer version 4.2.2). See attached screenshots. There is an additional artifact on the LHS wheel and the foot on the RHS is out of place. Any ideas?

[image: Model 1]

[image: Model 2]

Comment: Are both they translated recently? and viewed on the same viewer? If yes, please consider providing a none-confidential reproducible model demonstrating this issue to Forge Help channel ( forge.help@autodesk.com), I'm glad to help you pass it to our engineering team to investigate what happened if needed.

Comment: Could you consider the above suggestion?

Comment: Hi Eason, Yes, I will forward the model.